# Using jQuery, select first word of element and alter css

Tags: jquery, css, select

I've seen a lot of examples of how to take the first word of an element and add a span around it, giving that element a new class you can alter in CSS, but I have not been able to figure out how to just alter the CSS directly in jQuery.

I'm using this code to do the span thing right now:

```
$("h1").html(function(i, text){
  return text.replace(/\w+\s/, function(match){
    return '<span class="first_word"> + match + '</span>;
}); });
```

I'm trying to make the first word of titles a new color and font-family. It works for my h1, but i also have a widget title h3 that displays the added span in plain text when I add it to the selection. So I want to just change the css of the first word instead of adding a span.  (I also have no idea what "/\w+\s/" is doing so explaining that would be an added bonus :) )

Thank you wise ones!

Comment: Thank you for your help all. It seems I can't do exactly what I'm looking for but your answers have been helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **first-letter** and a **first-line** pseudo element but there is no first-word.   You need the span.

Comment: So I cannot make a CSS property change to a string held in a variable? Only to classes or IDs?

Comment: Right.  There are no CSS selectors for arbitrary string segments.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you have 2 questions.

How can I modify the code above to make it works with H1 and H3 and the second question is about the regex /\w+\s/.

1) You can just use Jquery multiple selector:

```
$("h1, h3").html(function(i, text){
  return text.replace(/\w+\s/, function(match){
    return '<span class="first_word"> + match + '</span>;
}); });
```

For more documentation you can see [JQuery Documentation for multiselector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

2) /\w+\s/ is a Regex Expression. It's three part expression. The first one is \w that represent any "word" character. It's a shortcut for : [a-zA-Z0-9_]. The second is the + that will let you have multiple [a-zA-Z0-9_]. It will group these characters to create a word and the last part is the \s that say to match the word until a space appear. You can get additionnal information about Regex Word Boundary in this [Regex Documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: That explains the second question very well, thank you! I'm not looking to add a span though. I guess I am wanting to assign a CSS change to "match" without adding a span or giving it a class. Maybe it is not allowed to assign CSS properties to variables, only change a class or ID?

Comment: "Jarrod" Right... Class, Id, or Tag.

Answer (score 2):

For first word changes.....

```
$('h1').each(function() {
var jqt = $(this);
var txt = jqt.text();
jqt.html('<span style="font-size:200%">'+txt.substring(0,(txt.indexOf(" ")))+'</span>'+ txt.substring((txt.indexOf(" "))));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script simply edits `h1` content's HTML and
surrounds words (the `\w+` RegEx) with a `span` element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
    $('h1').each(function(){
     var me = $(this);
     me.html(me.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
});

});
```

CSS

```
h1 span {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide an explanation of your code.

Comment: Greenonile... So the css will alter every span inside an "h1" tag... the JQuery is supposed put the span in every "h1" wrapped around the "first word".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .css method.  cf. http://api.jquery.com/css/

You may want something like

```
$(".first_word").css('color', 'red');
```

or so.

Also: /\w+\s/ is a regular expression saying a word followed by whitespace.

Comment: Did you mean:  $(".first_word").css('color', 'red');

Comment: `.css()` sounds like what the OP is asking for, but the selector does need to be modified as @Steve mentions.